# Given $A=\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $B=[-\pi,\pi]$, is $A\cup B=B$ true? $\Bbb{Z}\cap B=\{−3,−2,−1,0,1,2,3\}$? (and three others)

Tags: integers, natural-numbers

I was given these two sets of numbers:

$$A=\{0,1,2,3\}\qquad B=[−π,π]\;\;\text{(closed interval)}$$

Are these two correct? (I think yes.)

1. $A\cup B=B$
2. $\Bbb{Z}\cap B=\{−3,−2,−1,0,1,2,3\}$

I was also given these (in my opinion, they are false):

3. $(\Bbb{Z}−A)\subset\Bbb{N}$
4. $\Bbb{N}\cap B=A$
5. $A\cup B=A$

$\Bbb{Z}$ - integers, $\Bbb{N}$ - natural numbers (without $0$)

Thx

Comment: Are the angle brackets on $B$ supposed to represent an open interval?  It would be more usual to use parentheses or outward facing square brackets.  The truth of $\Bbb N \cap B =A$ depends on whether you think $0$ is a natural number.

Comment: B is closed interval <x,x>. Better [x,x].

Null should not be part of natural numbers in this case, thats why I have chosen this option.

Comment: Then I agree with you on all of them

Comment: Your answers would still be correct if $0 \in \Bbb N$, so that is not an issue. Since $A$ contains negatives, you still have elements of $A$ not in $\Bbb N$.